# PayPal REST API failed to capture order

Tags: python, api, rest, paypal, gdscript

I am using PayPal REST API to integrate payments in my app. I am currently in Sandbox Mode and i set app the sandbox app. I have clied ID and secret, and i am asking via code for access token. I am able to retrieve the token and then proceed to create an order. Order created and then i try to capture this order...Here we go... no matter what i tried, i got error 403, my token lacks permissions. My endpoint URL is correct for Sandbox, my auth credencials also correct Bearer access_token, and i check all the marks in paypal dev console... What i am missing here??? After weeks of studying the documentation, i am in dead end about why this happening, maybe my token missing a specific scope, if yes WHY?I can provide a code if needed but you understad the process here.

```
func get_order(order_id):
    var request = $HTTPRequest3
    var headers = PoolStringArray()
    headers.append("Content-Type: application/json")
    headers.append("Authorization: Bearer " +  access_token)
    headers.append("Accept: application/json")
    request.request(
        "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/" + order_id + "/capture",
        headers,
        true,
        HTTPClient.METHOD_POST
    )
    request.connect("request_completed", self, "_get_order_response")
```

this is the part that gives the 403 response about token..

Here is how i request my access token, i get a 200 response, client id and secret are encoded as they should (btw thx for the support)

```
func get_access_token():
var request = $HTTPRequest
var headers = PoolStringArray()
headers.append("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
headers.append("Authorization: Basic " + client_id + ":" + client_secret)
headers.append("Accept-Language: en_US")
headers.append("Accept: application/json")
var body = "grant_type=client_credentials"
request.request(
    "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    headers,
    true,
    HTTPClient.METHOD_POST,
    body
)
request.connect("request_completed", self, "_on_access_token_response")
```

And here is the order creation, this returns 201 code

```
func paypal_process():
var request = $HTTPRequest2
var headers = PoolStringArray()
headers.append("Content-Type: application/json")
headers.append("Authorization: Bearer " + access_token)
headers.append("Accept: application/json")
var body = {
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": "10.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
request.request(
    "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders",
    headers,
    true,
    HTTPClient.METHOD_POST,
    JSON.print(body)
)
request.connect("request_completed", self, "_on_paypal_response")
```

Comment: The response code is 403, what is the body of the response? This should have information about the error. For instance, was the order approved by a payer? See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ for an example of using smart buttons for payer approval.

Comment: response body
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource."}],"message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"3317730af144f","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PERMISSION_DENIED","rel":"information_link"}]}

Comment: How are you requesting your `access_token`?  put it in the question

Comment: Update for this topic : I didnt manage to make paypal REST API work with gdscript and my standalone app for windows, so i had to make a workaround. The way, node.js, setup and API server and handle the request from there with the node libraries for paypal. Finally make this node.js to communicate with my app in case the procedure was Complete.